# input[type=color] with predefined values not working since chromium 107

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, colors, chromium

I have an `input[type=color]` with some predefined values:

```html
<datalist id="5sui88f">
  <option>#1973ff</option>
  <option>#7F23FF</option>
  <option>#ff4136</option>
  <option>#ff851b</option>
  <option>#ffeb10</option>
  <option>#00db60</option>
</datalist>

<input type="color" list="5sui88f" id="picker">
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ds0kax25/1/

In Chromium based browsers, this results in a nice list of predefined colors to choose from:

[image: color dropdown in chrome]

This worked completely fine in older Chromium versions. However, since Chromium 107 selecting any value from the predefined list always sets `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` as the value of the input which [isn't even a valid value for a color input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/color#using_color_inputs).

In Chromium 106 this works without any problems. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this is indeed a chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1380977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1380977

I just checked it in Chrome 109 and it seems to work fine there.

Answer (score 0):

As kolaente already said, it's a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1383269

The bug is present on my setup too, Google Chrome 107.0.5304.110 on macOS too.